# Dynamic nested collapsible javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i have a menu on the left side. under that there is a sub menu called vod, under vod there is subject, under subject there is topic, under topic there are some videos. and all these data coming by ajax call to respected apis (like class-> class 10,class 11,class12; class10-> maths,english; maths-> algebra,calculus; algebra-> respected video and so on)

here is the first level

```
<div id="vodExpand" class="navbar nav1" style="display:none">
        
        </div>




    function liveVODKK(){

    
    $('#replaceUpcoming').css('display','none');
    $('#upcomingSchedule').css('display','none');
    $('#liveChannel').css('display','none');
    $('#channel').css('display','none');
    $('#createTest').css('display','none');
    $('#mcqTest').css('display','none');
    $('#editMcq').css('display','none');
    $('#courseUpload').css('display','none');
    $('#liveVod').css('display','none');
    $('#vod').css('display','none');
    $('#tAnnouncements').css('display','none');
    $('#sAnnouncements').css('display','none');
    $('#studentMcq').css('display','none');
    $('#questionsSet').css('display','none');
    $('#studentResult').css('display','none');
    $('#classReports').css('display','none');
    
    $('#liveChannelView').css('display','none');
    $('#liveVodView').css('display','none');
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://51.81.106.157/education_admin_api/vod.php',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
        },
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            'task' : 'get_vod_class'
        },      
        success:function(json){
            $('#vodExpand').css('display','block');
            $('#vodExpand').empty();
            for(var i=0; i<json.data.length;i++)
            {
                
                $('#vodExpand').append('<li class="nav-item dropdown">'+
                        '<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle white_left_link" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-file-text icon_menu" aria-hidden="true"></i> VOD</a>'+
                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">'+
                        '<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" onclick=subjectForVodClass('+json.data[i].id+') data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#vodClassExpand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-language icon_menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+json.data[i].vod_class_name+'</a></li>'+
                        '<input type="hidden" id="vodClassId" value="'+json.data[i].id+'">'+
                        
                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" id="vodClassExpand" style="display:none">'
                        
                        );
                
                
            
            }
            //liveVodKK();
            
            
            
            //dateTimePicker();
            
            
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
    
    
}
```

here is the 2nd level

```
function subjectForVodClass(vodClassId){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://51.81.106.157/education_admin_api/vod.php',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
        },
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            'task' : 'get_vod_class_subject',
            'vod_class_id' : vodClassId
        },      
        success:function(json){
            
            $('#vodExpand').css('display','block');
            //$('#vodExpand').empty();
            
            $('#vodClassExpand').css('display','block');
            $('#vodClassExpand').empty();
            for(var i=0; i<json.data.length;i++)
            {
                //$('#vodExpand').append('<p><a href="#" class="white_left_link" onclick=viewVodKK("'+json.data[i].vod_source+'","'+json.data[i].id+'","'+json.data[i].vod_name.replace(/\s/g, "")+'")><i class="fa fa-file-text icon_menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+json.data[i].vod_name +'</a></p>');
                $('#vodClassExpand').append('<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3" onclick=topicForVodSubject('+json.data[i].id+') data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#vodClassSubjectExpand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-language icon_menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+json.data[i].vod_subject_name+'</a></li>'+
                        '<input type="hidden" id="vodClassSubjectId" value="'+json.data[i].id+'">'+
                        
                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="vodClassSubjectExpand" style="display:none">'
                        
                        );
                //topicForVodSubject();
                //subjectForVodClass(vodClassId);
            
            }
            
            
            
            //dateTimePicker();
            
            
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
    
    
}
```

here is 3rd level

```
function topicForVodSubject(vodSubjectId){
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://51.81.106.157/education_admin_api/vod.php',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'${sessionScope.token}'
        },
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            'task' : 'get_vod_class_subject_topic',
            'vod_subject_id' : vodSubjectId
        },      
        success:function(json){
            
            $('#vodExpand').css('display','block');
            //$('#vodExpand').empty();
            
            $('#vodClassExpand').css('display','block');
            //$('#vodClassExpand').empty();
            
            $('#vodClassSubjectExpand').css('display','block');
            $('#vodClassSubjectExpand').empty();
            for(var i=0; i<json.data.length;i++)
            {
                
                
                $('#vodClassSubjectExpand').append('<li><a class="dropdown-item" id="viewVodKK" href="#" onclick=viewVodKK("'+json.data[i].vod_topic_source+'")><i class="fa fa-video-camera icon_menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+json.data[i].vod_topic_name+'</a></li>'+
                                                                '</ul>'+
                                                            '</ul>'+                            
                                                        '</ul>'+
                                                    '</li>'
                                                  );
                //topicForVodSubject(vodSubjectId);
            
            }
            
            
            
            //dateTimePicker();
            
            
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
    
    
}
```

so every level is dependent on previous level value i.e. id

here is the output
[image: o/p]

now the problem is every time I click on any intermediate level(like maths) the whole sub menu collaps . i have to click on the vod bar then it's get expanded then the data is loaded.
so the whole point is i cannot toggle in the intermidiate level.
how can i fix this?
any other javascript or jquery solutions are welcomed
thank you

Comment: solved , tried with different css class